# Using .find method with hidden workbook

Tags: excel, find, hidden, userform, vba

Is it possible to use `.find` method to look for data in a hidden workbook?

I have userform, which saves data to opened (but hidden) workbook. I want to make sure that when I enter invoive in one of textbox it was not inserted before.

I thought about using `.find` method but it gives me error 91 object variable or with block not set.

I checked those variable and they are set but I came up with an idea it may not go well with hidden workbook.

Below I pasted part of code. Error appears at `If skoroszyt...`

```
If Lastrow <> 1 And nr_faktury <> "" Then



    If skoroszyt.Worksheets(nazwa_arkusza).Range(faktury_range).Find(nr_faktury) = True Then
        MsgBox ("Podany nr faktury został podany w fakturze nr" & _
        skoroszyt.Worksheets(nazwa_arkusza).Range(faktury_range).Find(nr_faktury).Address & vbNewLine & _
        "Faktura nie została zapisana")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End If
```

Comment: do you mean `If Not skoroszyt.Worksheets(nazwa_arkusza).Range(faktury_range).Find(nr_faktury) Is Nothing Then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this one:

```
Dim rng As Range

If Lastrow <> 1 And nr_faktury <> "" Then
    Set rng = skoroszyt.Worksheets(nazwa_arkusza).Range(faktury_range).Find(What:=nr_faktury, _
                                                                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                                            MatchCase:=False)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Podany nr faktury zostal podany w fakturze nr" & _
            rng.Address & vbNewLine & "Faktura nie zostala zapisana"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

for partial match, change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`

Comment: Nice! I thought it was caused by my workbook being hidden but it came up to be wrong if statement :) Thanks simoco, it works excacly as I wanted.